# EntityFramework Core: "The entity type 'Role' requires a primary key to be defined", but I have no Role entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

##### Environment info

I'm working with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 3.1.2.

##### Background

I did some refactoring to split models into separate contexts in separate assemblies. The newly created context works fine, but the old context throws

> The entity type 'Role' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()',

The issue is that the old context no longer has a `Role` type.

I've tried

- text search, no Role references
- symbol search, no Role references
- clean and rebuild, still broken
- delete bin and obj, still broken
- restart VS, still broken

I've also searched about model caching. It would seem migrations store a model representation, but I'm using an in-memory database that should be different every time.

##### Stack Trace

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
...
```

##### Question

Any ideas what could be holding onto the model or other potential issues?

Comment: How about reference(s) to something which in turn references `Role`? As explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#including-types-in-the-model), entity types are discovered and included recursively.

Comment: Is this your role model or Identity roles?

Comment: Can you also please share your old and new context include any `OnModelCreating` methods you may have across the codebase?

Comment: @IvanStoev Role is not defined in an assembly not referenced by the assembly with the failing context

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I don't think I understand what difference that would make. The context is plain EF DbContext. It's not a special derivative for an identity framework or such

Comment: @farlee2121 It may make a difference if it was Identity role as I thought perhaps you still had code for enabling Identity roles in your project which may have impacted this - thanks for the clarification

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I'll ask about sharing the context. It's effectively only OnModelCreating and the DbSets

Comment: If you're not referencing any role model anywhere, no need @farlee2121

Does that exception throw on any communication with the DbContext or just a particular model?

Comment: Great question. I'll add that to the original post. It errors on the first call to the DbContext. The stacktrace shows it's during the internal model validation

Comment: @farlee2121 Apparently it *is* referenced/included indirectly, otherwise you won't get that error. Migrations has nothing to do with this, they don't use strongly typed entity classes. Here is what you can do - go and type the following at the end of `OnModelCreating` of the problematic `DbContext`: `foreach (var entityType in modeBuilder.GetEntityTypes()) Debug.Print(entityType.Name);` This will list all the entity types discovered by EF Core using the methodology from the link. You'll see there `Role`, and may be other classes you think are not there, then just find who is including them.

Comment: Turns out there was a `User` navigation property that didn't get removed and it found another User type to reference, which then was referencing a different `Role` type, which was what happened to throw the error. What a weird string of coincidences. Thank you both for your help! I'd be happy to dish out points if you want to create an answer